# ClassNotFound Error when compiling multiple object classes

Tags: java, class, object, compiler-construction

I have a Store class which is an array of Person; I have a Person, Date, Student, Undergraduate and Postgraduate classes. Everything runs in Eclipse, and I have to run this from the Command Line. I've copied the src files and tried to run the main program, but it's just saying it can't find any of my classes. They are all in the same folder and in every class I have assigned the package. I've looked up importing classes and I tried:

```
    import oopinterface.Person;
```

etc for all classes.

Is there any way I can compile the main program so it will recognise the class files that are very clearly there!? I'm on Windows, but it would help if I could have the 'other' way for Linux?

This is the Compiler error:

```
   C:\Users\Liloka\Source\oopinterface>javac ContainerInterface.java
   ContainerInterface.java:41: cannot find symbol
   symbol  : class Store
   location: class oopinterface.ContainerInterface
            Store myList = new Store();

   //Instance of Store
                    ^
   ContainerInterface.java:688: cannot find symbol
   symbol  : class Person
   location: class oopinterface.ContainerInterface
            public Person getSupervisor()
                   ^
```

.. it goes on to pick at every method in other classes.. (39)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your classes are in the package `oopinterface`. Compile the source files from the base directory of the package, like this:

```
C:\Users\Liloka\Source> javac oopinterface\ContainerInterface.java
```

If you have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set, then make sure that it is not set, or add the base directory of the package where the compiled class files can be found to the classpath. You can also use the `-cp` or `-classpath` option to tell `javac` where to find the compiled class files.

Do all your source files have a `package oopinterface;` at the top of the file?

After compiling, to run the program from the command line do something like this:

```
java -cp C:\Users\Liloka\Source oopinterface.MainClass
```

where `MainClass` is the class that contains the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. (This assumes that your compiled class files are in the same directory as the sources).

Comment: Yes they do, and I did compile them all at once, but I was in oopinterface and just ran javac *.java which didn't give me any errors until I ran my Container class. It compiled successfully with your suggestion, but it's still giving me the same error when I try and run ContainerInterface :/

Comment: I've tried running it and it worked!! My ContainerInterface was my main class.. So thank you so much! You just saved my uni project!

Answer (score 1):

You should compile all your classes at once, since they all reference themselves. cd to the Source directory, and run

```
javac oopinterface\*.java
```

Comment: That doesn't give me any compile errors, but how do I run it? I tried:

       java oopinterface\ContainerInterface

but it's not working :/

Comment: You need to give the full class name to java: java -cp . oopinterface.ContainerInterface (provided you're still in the Source directory)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the class path to point to the directory where the your classes are so the compiler and interpreter commands can find it.
It looks like: javac -classpath C:\Users\Liloka\Source\oopinterface ContainerInterface.java